# Multi-Session handling web-browsers?

Tags: browser, browser-addons

Do web browsers exist with 'multi-session' functionality? I think thats the best way of describing what I'm after.

My problem is I have multiple facebook/twitter etc accounts for different projects and it's a pain remembering details logging in/out of each and even more-so when combined with work's accounts. I guess 'tabbed, tabbed' browsing that doesn't share cookies would be ideal.

Is there a good browser that sports this functionality in existance, or any firefox addons etc?

For the moment I'm using private browsing in Firefox, but that is only so much use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox (and other products in the Mozilla suite, such as SeaMonkey) has a [profile manager](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_manager), which provides a UI to manage user profiles.  You can skip the UI and select it one to use with the `-profile` switch.

You can run multiple Google Chrome instances with a different `--user-data-dir` locations; each will be a different profile.  There's on-going work to build [multi-profiles](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/multi-profiles) into the UI.

Comment: I'll take a look at SeaMonkey, thanks. It sounds like Google are thinking along the right lines (or at least my lines =) ) with multi-profiles.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Windows**, you can 'install' multiple iterations of [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable), as an alternative to using the **Profile Manager** via `firefox --profilemanager`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any browsers that support multiple sessions, but there are two workarounds I can suggest.

Option 1: Use multiple browsers

You could use Firefox for personal stuff and Chrome for work stuff. Each browser has its own session, cookies, favorites, etc.

Option 2: Use multiple user accounts

Sometimes I need to log in to our corporate intranet system as the admin user, but don't want to log out of my own user. In Windows, when you right-click an icon there is an option called "Run as..." which lets you run the application as a different user without having to log off Windows.

Comment: Would using run-as... in Windows start Firefox with a session linked to that windows user account? That could be problem solved, if so. I do use multiple browsers sometimes, but I'm attached to my firefox addons. =)

Comment: I ran into something similar a while ago, and I generally use FireFox for almost all of my browsing, but I keep Chrome around when I need to log in with multiple accounts at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

A different idea, if you want to handle multiple FB/Twitter accounts I would recommend using the Yoono Firefox AddOn, it shows each twitter account separately and you can update them also. (I have used it mainly for twitter, but the FB support should be similar)
http://www.yoono.com

Answer (score -1):

Try Ghost Browser!

https://ghostbrowser.com/#smm

Yes, finally! A browser that now specifically allows separating a tab or group of tabs among a specific "session", i.e. be logged into different twitter, gmail, facebook... accounts at the same time in the same browser window across different tabs all without requiring an extra add-on or ext to be installed.

Comment: This looks very much like spam - promoting a product that to be of any use requires payment. Given there are alternative free solutions (for example I can already login to multiple gmail accounts within a single firefox session without using addons) what does the product give us that free alternative don't?

Comment: - No, not spam, I have nothing to gain and the link I shared is the only true answer of all answers to the very first question, a "browser", out of box with the specific feature of having separate color-coded tabs grouped by session.

- No it does not require payment of any kind.  I've been using the free version for some time now.  I do agree the limits might be too restrictive for some.

Maybe you should ask before jumping to conclusions and marking answers down. Gawd, I hate this place and you know why, people like you rebuking people left and right just for trying to help out.